# Change value of member of mocked service with Jasmine

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm using Jasmine in an Angular app to test a component that uses a service that has been mocked with `createSpyObject()`.  The mocked service contains some members that are manipulated directly by the component under test.  I'm trying to assert that those values have been set correctly by the component.

Here's the code:

The service:

```
export class SomeService {
    serviceMember = 0;

    firstFunc() {
        return 5;
    }
}
```

The component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-component',
  templateUrl: './my-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-component.component.css']
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private theService: SomeService) {
    }

    ...

    someFunc() {
        this.theService.serviceMember = 42;
    }
}
```

The unit test:

```
describe('My Component', () => {
  let component: MyComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;
  let someServiceSpy: any;

   beforeEach(async(() => {
    someServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('SomeService', {
      'firstFunc': 5
    });

    someServiceSpy = {
      ...someServiceSpy,
      serviceMember: 0
    };

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        MyComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        ...
      ],
      providers: [
        { provide: SomeService, useValue: someServiceSpy },
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents().then(() => {
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
      component = fixture.componentInstance;

      fixture.detectChanges();
    });
  });

  it('should update service member', () => {
    component.someFunc();

    expect(someServiceSpy.serviceMember).toBe(42);
  });
});
```

The test always fails with `serviceMember` still containing 0. I've tried all kinds of things, including `spyOnProperty`, with no luck.  Anyone have a suggestion on how to test this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using angular TestBed it creates a copy of your providers that get sent into each `it` statement. This is so that each test gets an independent copy of each service and changes to them won't affect other tests.
In your case you are attempting to check if the original instance had a property set. To do this you need to grab the instance of the service provided to that test.

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { MyComponent } from './my.component';
import { SomeService } from './some.service';

describe('MyComponent', () => {
  let component: MyComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;
  let someServiceSpy: SomeService;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    someServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj<SomeService>('SomeService', ['firstFunc']);

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [MyComponent],
      providers: [{ provide: SomeService, useValue: someServiceSpy }]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  fit('should update service member', () => {
    const serviceInstance = TestBed.get(SomeService) as SomeService; // get test instance
    component.someFunc();

    expect(serviceInstance.serviceMember).toBe(42);
  });
});
```